# How does OpenSSL determine that a certificate is for a root CA?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls, x509

I have a Verisign intermediate certificate that was issued by a Verisign root CA. But when I ask OpenSSL to validate the chain **without** providing the root CA certificate, OpenSSL says the chain is valid. Why? The subject and issuer fields in the intermediate certificate are different.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
openssl verify -verbose VSIntermediate.pem
```

And here is the certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            2c:48:dd:93:0d:f5:59:8e:f9:3c:99:54:7a:60:ed:43
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  8 00:00:00 2006 GMT
            Not After : Nov  7 23:59:59 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:bd:56:88:ba:88:34:64:64:cf:cd:ca:b0:ee:e7:
                    19:73:c5:72:d9:bb:45:bc:b5:a8:ff:83:be:1c:03:
                    db:ed:89:b7:2e:10:1a:25:bc:55:ca:41:a1:9f:0b:
                    cf:19:5e:70:b9:5e:39:4b:9e:31:1c:5f:87:ae:2a:
                    aa:a8:2b:a2:1b:3b:10:23:5f:13:b1:dd:08:8c:4e:
                    14:da:83:81:e3:b5:8c:e3:68:ed:24:67:ce:56:b6:
                    ac:9b:73:96:44:db:8a:8c:b3:d6:f0:71:93:8e:db:
                    71:54:4a:eb:73:59:6a:8f:70:51:2c:03:9f:97:d1:
                    cc:11:7a:bc:62:0d:95:2a:c9:1c:75:57:e9:f5:c7:
                    ea:ba:84:35:cb:c7:85:5a:7e:e4:4d:e1:11:97:7d:
                    0e:20:34:45:db:f1:a2:09:eb:eb:3d:9e:b8:96:43:
                    5e:34:4b:08:25:1e:43:1a:a2:d9:b7:8a:01:34:3d:
                    c3:f8:e5:af:4f:8c:ff:cd:65:f0:23:4e:c5:97:b3:
                    5c:da:90:1c:82:85:0d:06:0d:c1:22:b6:7b:28:a4:
                    03:c3:4c:53:d1:58:bc:72:bc:08:39:fc:a0:76:a8:
                    a8:e9:4b:6e:88:3d:e3:b3:31:25:8c:73:29:48:0e:
                    32:79:06:ed:3d:43:f4:f6:e4:e9:fc:7d:be:8e:08:
                    d5:1f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                4E:43:C8:1D:76:EF:37:53:7A:4F:F2:58:6F:94:F3:38:E2:D5:BD:DF
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
                  CPS: https://www.verisign.com/cps

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://EVSecure-crl.verisign.com/pca3-g5.crl

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL CA, S/MIME CA
            1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12: 
                0_.].[0Y0W0U..image/gif0!0.0...+..............k...j.H.,{..0%.#http://logo.verisign.com/vslogo.gif
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DirName:/CN=Class3CA2048-1-48
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:7F:D3:65:A7:C2:DD:EC:BB:F0:30:09:F3:43:39:FA:02:AF:33:31:33

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://EVSecure-ocsp.verisign.com

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                Netscape Server Gated Crypto, 2.16.840.1.113733.1.8.1, TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         27:74:a6:34:ea:1d:9d:e1:53:d6:1c:9d:0c:a7:5b:4c:a9:67:
         f2:f0:32:b7:01:0f:fb:42:18:38:de:e4:ee:49:c8:13:c9:0b:
         ec:04:c3:40:71:18:72:76:43:02:23:5d:ab:7b:c8:48:14:1a:
         c8:7b:1d:fc:f6:0a:9f:36:a1:d2:09:73:71:66:96:75:51:34:
         bf:99:30:51:67:9d:54:b7:26:45:ac:73:08:23:86:26:99:71:
         f4:8e:d7:ea:39:9b:06:09:23:bf:62:dd:a8:c4:b6:7d:a4:89:
         07:3e:f3:6d:ae:40:59:50:79:97:37:3d:32:78:7d:b2:63:4b:
         f9:ea:08:69:0e:13:ed:e8:cf:bb:ac:05:86:ca:22:cf:88:62:
         5d:3c:22:49:d8:63:d5:24:a6:bd:ef:5c:e3:cc:20:3b:22:ea:
         fc:44:c6:a8:e5:1f:e1:86:cd:0c:4d:8f:93:53:d9:7f:ee:a1:
         08:a7:b3:30:96:49:70:6e:a3:6c:3d:d0:63:ef:25:66:63:cc:
         aa:b7:18:17:4e:ea:70:76:f6:ba:42:a6:80:37:09:4e:9f:66:
         88:2e:6b:33:66:c8:c0:71:a4:41:eb:5a:e3:fc:14:2e:4b:88:
         fd:ae:6e:5b:65:e9:27:e4:bf:e4:b0:23:c1:b2:7d:5b:62:25:
         d7:3e:10:d4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `openssl verify` openssl will attempt to use a `CAFile` path you specify, if one does not exist it loads the default verify path which is selected when compiled.

On my system that is `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem`.

Comment: I tried adding -CAfile using a different (completely unrelated) certificate file. OpenSSL still says the intermediate cert is valid.

Comment: Your system may have a directory of trusted certificate files rather than a single big file. Try overriding `-CApath` as well as `-CAfile`.

Comment: Setting -CApath to /dev/null worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While Openssl itself does not include any root CA certificates, most operating system distributions that include openssl do include such certificates, so you probably already have the Verisign root certificate installed on your system. For example in Debian Linux, they're in the ca-certificates package.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to ignore those default certificates?